# d3.time.scale() returning NAN

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to follow this example:http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

However, when trying to replicate to my needs values for x scale being returned in NAN. Values for y scale returns fine. Kindly help me to find out what I a doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.key); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.values.total); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
d3.csv("combine.csv", function(error, data) {

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.week = parseDate(d.week);

  });

    data= d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.week; })
.rollup(function(d) { return {"total": d.length , hours: d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.hours; })};})
.entries(data);


  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { console.log(d.key);return d.key; }));
  console.log(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.key; }));

  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { console.log( d.values.total);return d.values.total; }));
 console.log(data);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});




</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use actual `Date` objects, not just the string. So you can update the following lines to fix it:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
    return x(new Date(d.key));
});
```

And

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return new Date(d.key);
}));
```

I created a fiddle simulating your data: http://jsfiddle.net/LRY7w/

---

Alternatively, you could add the `week` property to the object you're returning from the `rollup`. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRY7w/2/) and here's the revised rollup function:

```
.rollup(function (d) {
    return {
        week: d[0].week,
        "total": d.length,
        hours: d3.sum(d, function (g) {
            return g.hours;
        })
    };
})
```

Have to use `d[0]` since `d` is the nested rows, but since you're keying off of the week, it's the same in each object of the array, so using the first works just fine. And then instead of using `new Date(d.key)`, you can just use `d.values.week`.

Comment: Thanks a ton Kalley. Just one question. Why do we have to use actual Date objects when we are parsing it as date. In my data array key value is in format "Sat Jun 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)". Hence why there is a need to explicitly define it as date.

Comment: Because `d3.nest` is turning your `week` property into string. I've added another way to do this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Kelly. Can you help me once again for this query.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831411/d3-data-table-query