# D3 data table query

Tags: d3.js, datatables

I want to create an expandable table. Suppose  I have following records in table:

```
Sr.No   Type
1   Planets
1.1 Mercury
1.2 Earth
1.3 Venus
2   Colors
2.1 Yellow
2.2 Green

Default view should be :
Sr.No   Type
1       Planets
2       Colors
```

and when one clicks on Planet row, it should expand as:

```
Sr.No   Type
1   Planets
1.1 Mercury
1.2 Earth
1.3 Venus
2   Colors
```

and on clicking once again it should rollback to original state.

Kindly guide me or point me to some reference. Also,if this is not possible, is there anything close to this  possible in d3. Thanks.

Comment: This might be something in the right direction: http://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/