# d3.js query regarding dynamic line chart

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3. Would be grateful if someone answer my folowing doubts:

On clicking a radio button i am updating the line chart using following code

```
d3.selectAll(".line").attr("d", line);
```

However, this updates all the line charts present on page. How do I update line corresponding to this particular graph.

Comment: You could perhaps modify your selector to be more specific.  For example: `d3.selectAll("#graph1 .line")...`

Comment: We'll need more information to tell what exactly is going on.

Comment: Pls consider this as example: http://bl.ocks.org/rajatgupta13/a41d9cc1e7e8fe87c7be I dont know why lines are not coming. They are comming on my local.But this will explain. When I check radio box of one graph other also get triggered. Kindly explain how to tackle this. Also, i want both graphs to be side by side. Kindly explain how to do that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must label each chart in some way, then use that in the selection.
Set an ID on each chart #chart-1, #chart-2, ..., #chart-n

The select either like this:

```
d3.selectAll("#chart-1 .line").attr("d", line);
```

or

```
d3.select("#chart-1").selectAll(".line").attr("d", line);
```

With the second one you can store the chart and use it later, it's more efficient then:

```
var chart1 = d3.select("chart-1");
// ...possibly other code
chart1.selectAll(".line").attr("d", line);
```

Comment: Pls consider this as example: bl.ocks.org/rajatgupta13/a41d9cc1e7e8fe87c7be I dont know why lines are not coming. They are comming on my local.But this will explain. When I check radio box of one graph other also get triggered. Kindly explain how to tackle this. Also, i want both graphs to be side by side. Kindly explain how to do that also.

Comment: It's the same problem @Raj but for inputs. You are selecting ALL the input's and adding code to fire when EITHER is clicked `d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change)` - Put an ID on your form and select the right one! `d3.selectAll("#form-1 input").on("change", change)...`

Comment: Thanks a lot Mattew.Now I understand fine about this concept. Request you to please take a look at my another query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831411/d3-data-table-query.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a selection of charts:

```
var charts = d3.selectAll('.line').data(data);
charts.enter().append('path').attr('class', 'line').attr('d', line);
```

To work with a specific chart, just [`filter`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter) your charts seletion:

```
var chart;
chart = charts.filter(function(d) { d.name === selectedGraph; });
// or
chart = charts.filter('#chart-' + selectedGraph)
```